# Firestore infinite loading Vue

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuetify.js

***Update*** Added a data binding for "lastVisible" to make it more dynamic

***Problem*** When I scroll to the bottom, I get 2 of the same products loading, and then when I continue scrolling, I get the same product, but only one at a time. It's like it doesn't update the "lastVisible" binding.
Video: http://recordit.co/z0LtPReQ8Q

I'm trying to incorporate infinite loading, where more products will load when the user scrolls to the bottom of the window.

```js
import db from "../firebase/firebaseInit";
import firebase from "firebase";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      lastVisible: [],
      straps: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getStraps()
  },
  methods: {
    getStraps() {
      var first = db.collection("straps").limit(2);
      first.get().then(documentSnapshots => {
        this.lastVisible =
          documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1];
        const straps = [];
        documentSnapshots.forEach(doc => {
          const data = {
            id: doc.id,
            title: doc.data().title,
            price: doc.data().price,
            skin: doc.data().skin,
            type: doc.data().type,
            imgs: doc.data().imgs[0].url,
            colors: doc.data().colors,
            desc: doc.data().desc,
            date: doc
              .data()
              .date.toString()
              .slice(0, 15)
          };
          straps.push(data);
          console.log("first data", data);
          console.log("visible", this.lastVisible);
        });
        this.straps = straps;
        var next = db
          .collection("straps")
          .startAfter(this.lastVisible)
          .limit(1);

        window.onscroll = () => {
          let bottomOfWindow =
            document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight ===
            document.documentElement.offsetHeight;

          if (bottomOfWindow) {
            next.get().then(documentSnapshots => {
            this.lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1];
              documentSnapshots.forEach(doc => {
                const data = {
                  id: doc.id,
                  title: doc.data().title,
                  price: doc.data().price,
                  skin: doc.data().skin,
                  type: doc.data().type,
                  imgs: doc.data().imgs[0].url,
                  colors: doc.data().colors,
                  desc: doc.data().desc,
                  date: doc
                    .data()
                    .date.toString()
                    .slice(0, 15)
                };
                console.log("lastVisible", this.lastVisible);
                console.log("more data", data);
                this.straps.push(data);
              });
            });
          }
        };
      });
      console.log("window", bottomOfWindow);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredStraps() {
      var straps = this.straps;

      if (this.search !== null) {
        var straps = this.searchItems.filter(strap => {
          if (!this.search) return this.searchItems;
          return (
            strap.desc.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
            strap.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
            strap.skin.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
            strap.type.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
            strap.colors.find(color => {
              return this.search
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(color.title.toLowerCase());
            })
          );
        });
      }

      if (this.slider) {}

      if (this.checkedSkins.length > 0) {
        straps = straps.filter(strap => {
          return this.checkedSkins.includes(strap.skin.toLowerCase());
        });
      }
      if (this.checkedTypes.length > 0) {
        straps = straps.filter(strap => {
          return this.checkedTypes.includes(strap.type.toLowerCase());
        });
      }
      if (this.checkedColors.length > 0) {
        straps = straps.filter(strap => {
          return strap.colors.find(color => {
            return this.checkedColors.includes(color.title.toLowerCase());
          });
        });
      }

      if (this.sort == "newest") {
        return straps.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date));
      }
      if (this.sort == "priceasc") {
        return straps.sort((a, b) => a.price > b.price);
      }
      if (this.sort == "pricedesc") {
        return straps.sort((a, b) => a.price < b.price);
      } else {
        return straps;
      }
    }
  },
```

```html
<v-layout justify-start wrap>
  <v-flex xs12 pa-3 sm4 lg2 v-for="strap in filteredStraps" :key="strap.id">
    <v-hover>
      <v-card :to="{name: 'Strap', params: {id: strap.id}}" flat slot-scope="{ hover }">
        <v-img :src="strap.imgs" aspect-ratio="1">
          <v-layout class="grey lighten-1" slot="placeholder" fill-height align-center justify-center ma-0>
            <v-progress-circular indeterminate color="grey darken-1"></v-progress-circular>
          </v-layout>
        </v-img>
        <v-card-title primary-title>
          <h3 class="text-xs-left">{{strap.title | capitalize}}</h3>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text style="padding: 0 !important;">
          <p class="text-xs-left">{{strap.price}} kr.</p>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-hover>
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

The computed properties are working, except for the slider, but that's not the point of the question. I'm looking for an answer to my infinite loading method in getStraps(), to load more products when the user scrolls to the bottom of the window.

Comment: You should elaborate on your question because you could have easily given more information. What part is not working? Is it the scroll that is not working or the firebase call? You could easily test these things but simply putting this straight in your `created` call and testing them more isolated.

Comment: I dont see the Infinite Loading Component anywhere in your HTML :)

Comment: This answer actually worked. I tested some console logs for the lastVisible and loading more data. Now I just need the straps to be pushed to the "this.straps" without it reloading all the straps and displaying one. Check this updated link: http://recordit.co/S7SPRCKkqR

Comment: @Badgy There's no loading component, it's rather the method that handles the loading of products, when the window is scrolled to the bottom with the "bottomOfWindow" variable

Comment: @Stephan-v I've described it better, and added a video with the testings, if you don't mind taking another look

Comment: Did you fixed it? Please share it.